# Streamlines equation in a fixed frame

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reference-frames, flow

In this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow_around_a_circular_cylinder) about potential flow around circular cylinder, the stream function is given by:
 $$\psi =U\left(r-{\frac {R^{2}}{r}}\right)\sin \theta \tag{1}$$

But in [another article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streamlines,_streaklines,_and_pathlines#Frame_dependence) we can find that streamlines are frame dependent.

I am wondering in which reference frame the equation (1) is derived? if it is derived in the moving frame attached to cylinder, then how can I find the new equation of stream function in a fixed frame?

Comment: This is obviously for flow past a stationary cylinder.  In any other frame of reference, the. flow lines are time-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, the stream function is derived from a *linear* differential equation, by applying boundary conditions and integrating.

Because the differential equation is linear, solutions of the equation can be added together and still result in a solution to the equation. In this case, the equation you give for the flow is in a reference frame fixed to the cylinder. If it is not accelerating, you should be able to subtract the streamlines of a uniform flow with velocity $U$ to get the streamlines in an inertial (relative to the cylinder) reference frame.

Of course, this only works because the inviscid, incompressible potential equation was linearized. You cannot add independent solutions of non-linear equations and expect the sum to be a solution also. But, it works this time and can be used to great advantage -- rather complex flows can be made from adding sources, sinks, vortex, and doublet solutions many times.

Comment: I have a question: Why there is a difference of pathlines when: First case, Considering the cylinder moving while the fluid is at rest.  In the second case: The cylinder is fixed while the flow is moving around it?